# How to insert new instance into OWL ontology using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology

I want to insert a new instance into my ontology using SPARQL INSERT statement.
A sample instance:

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.test123.com/test123-ontology.owl#cap_123">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.test123.com/test123-ontology.owl#HealthBeauty"/>
<description>Test test test</description>
<hasPrice rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">49</hasPrice>
<id rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">123</id>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

A new instance that should be inserted has the following attributes:

```
id: 456
hasPrice: 15
description: "Test2 test2 test2"
```

I don't know how to complete the INSERT part of the query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.test123.com/test123-ontology.owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX oo:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
INSERT " 
{
//...
}
```

Comment: This is pretty clear documented in the W3C specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#insertData

Comment: @AKSW: I do not understand how to specify this part  `rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.test123.com/test123-ontology.owl#HealthBeauty"/>`

Comment: I do not understand. Everything is a triple, thus, it's simply `<http://www.test123.com/test123-ontology.owl#cap_123> rdf:type <http://www.test123.com/test123-ontology.owl#He‌​althBeauty> .`

Comment: I really suggest you to have a look at your data in TURTLE or N-Triples syntax. This is close to SPARQL triple patterns and of course triples.

Comment: In case you are using Protégé, SPARQL update is not implemented there.

Comment: @Dinosaurius If you got the solution, please post it as answer such that others can refer to it later.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov: No, I am using SPARQL from Java.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is the following:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.test123.com/test123-ontology.owl#> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX oo:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 

INSERT 
{ 
   owl:cap_456 rdf:type owl:HealthBeauty . 
   owl:cap_456 owl:id 456 . 
   owl:cap_456 owl:hasPrice 15 . 
   owl:cap_456 owl:description 'Test2 test2 test2' . } 
WHERE 
{ 
   FILTER NOT EXISTS 
   { 
     owl:cap_456 rdf:type owl:HealthBeauty . 
   } 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need a `WHERE` clause and didn't simply use `INSERT DATA` as I referred to in my previous comment. You don't have any triple pattern, i.e. no variables - simply triples. The `WHERE` clause is for matching patterns in the data

Comment: won't be needed an additional triplet inside the insert?
`owl:cap_456 rdf:type oo:NamedIndividual`

Answer (score 0):

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.test123.com/test123-ontology.owl#> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX oo:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 

INSERT DATA
{
   owl:cap_456 rdf:type owl:HealthBeauty;
               rdf:type oo:NamedIndividual;
               owl:id 456 ; 
               owl:hasPrice 15; 
               owl:description 'Test2 test2 test2' .
}
```